# threejs - better performance for my time script

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made some experiments with the great threejs lib:
https://maki-mikkelson.com/time

But the performance is very bad. Does somebody know what I could do better?

First there's my timeFont class from where I create every second (or by input) an instance of it. Below I initialize the camera, the scene, the light and the renderer. I delete the instance of it when it flies out of the scene.

I don't know what's eating more resources. Is it the fonts, is it that I update the text too much or did I just go over the limits of this lib.

Here's the source:

```
// timeFont class
class timeFont {

    constructor(scene = undefined, timeType = 'currentTimeString', startZPos = 0) {
        this.scene = scene;
        this.timeType = timeType;
        this.startZPos = startZPos;

        this.group, this.textMesh1, this.textGeo, this.materials;

        // set random speed
        this.speed = this.getRandomInt(10, 100);

        // set random y
        this.yOffset = this.getRandomArbitrary(-1.0, 1.0);

        // time strings
        this.timeStrings = {
            0: 'currentTimeString',
            1: 'currentMilliseconds',
            2: 'currentSeconds',
            3: 'currentMinutes',
            4: 'currentHours',
            5: 'currentDateString',
            6: 'currentDay',
            7: 'currentMonth',
            8: 'currentYear',
            9: 'currentTimestamp',
            10: 'mid'
        };

        this.currentTimeString,
        this.currentMilliseconds,
        this.currentSeconds,
        this.currentMinutes,
        this.currentHours,
        this.currentDateString,
        this.currentDay,
        this.currentMonth,
        this.currentYear,
        this.currentTimestamp,
        this.mid;

        // font settings
        this.fontMap = {
            0: "Alfa_Slab_One_Regular.json",
            1: "Comfortaa_Regular.json",
            2: "Freehand_Regular.json",
            3: "Mandali_Regular.json",
            4: "Monofett_Regular.json",
            5: "Raleway_Dots_Regular.json"
        };

        // update the clock initially
        this.updateClock();

        this.timeType = this.randomProperty(this.timeStrings);
        this.text = this.currentMilliseconds,

        this.height = this.getRandomInt(10, 100),
        this.size = this.getRandomInt(10, 100),
        this.hover = 0,

        this.curveSegments = 4,

        this.bevelThickness = 1.0,
        this.bevelSize = 1.5,

        this.font = undefined,
        this.fontName = this.randomProperty(this.fontMap);

    }

    randomProperty(obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        return obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
    };

    getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    initClass() {

        this.materials = [
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true, opacity: 0.5, depthWrite: false, transparent: true } ), // front
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5, depthWrite: false, transparent: true } ) // side
        ];

        this.group = new THREE.Group();
        this.group.position.y = 0;

        // load font
        this.loadFont();

        // add to scene
        if (this.scene) {
            this.scene.add(this.group);
        }

    }

    loadFont() {

        this.fontName = this.randomProperty(this.fontMap);

        var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        loader.load('assets/content/font/' + this.fontName, (response) => {
            this.font = response;
        });

    };

    createText() {

        this.textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(String(this.text), {

            font: this.font,

            size: this.size,
            height: this.height,
            curveSegments: this.curveSegments,

            bevelThickness: this.bevelThickness,
            bevelSize: this.bevelSize

        });

        this.textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
        this.textGeo.computeVertexNormals();

        var centerOffset = - 0.5 * ( this.textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - this.textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );

        this.textGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(this.textGeo);

        this.textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeo, this.materials);

        this.textMesh1.position.x = centerOffset;
        this.textMesh1.position.y = this.hover;
        this.textMesh1.position.z = 0;

        this.textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
        this.textMesh1.rotation.y = 0;
        this.textMesh1.rotation.z = 0;

        this.group.add(this.textMesh1);

    };

    updateText() {
        // remove old mesh
        this.group.remove(this.textMesh1);
        // create it again
        this.createText();
    }

    // time function
    updateClock() {
        var currentTime = new Date();

        this.currentDay = currentTime.getDate();
        this.currentMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        this.currentYear = currentTime.getFullYear();

        this.currentTimestamp = Date.now();

        this.currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
        this.currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        this.currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        this.currentMilliseconds = currentTime.getMilliseconds();

        // get AM / PM
        var hours = (this.currentHours+24-2)%24; 
        this.mid='am';
        if (hours==0) {
            hours=12;
        } else if (hours>12) {
            hours=hours%12;
            this.mid='pm';
        }

        // Pad the minutes with leading zeros, if required
        //currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes == 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
        if (this.currentMinutes < 10) {
            this.currentMinutes = '0' + this.currentMinutes;
        }

        // Pad the seconds with leading zeros, if required
        if (this.currentSeconds < 10) {
            this.currentSeconds = '0' + this.currentSeconds;
        }

        // Compose the string for display time
        this.currentTimeString = this.currentHours + ":" + this.currentMinutes + ":" + this.currentSeconds;

        // Compose the string for display date
        this.currentDateString = this.currentDay + "-" + this.currentMonth + "-" + this.currentYear;

        // set text
        switch(this.timeType) {
            case 'currentTimeString':
                this.text = this.currentTimeString;
                break;
            case 'currentMilliseconds':
                this.text = this.currentMilliseconds;
                break;
            case 'currentSeconds':
                this.text = this.currentSeconds;
                break;
            case 'currentMinutes':
                this.text = this.currentMinutes;
                break;
            case 'currentHours':
                this.text = this.currentHours;
                break;
            case 'currentDateString':
                this.text = this.currentDateString;
                break;
            case 'currentDay':
                this.text = this.currentDay;
                break;
            case 'currentMonth':
                this.text = this.currentMonth;
                break;
            case 'currentYear':
                this.text = this.currentYear;
                break;
            case 'currentTimestamp':
                this.text = this.currentTimestamp;
                break;
            case 'mid':
                this.text = this.mid;
                break;
            default:
                this.text = this.currentTimestamp;
        }

    };

    get timeFontZ() {
        return this.group.position.z;
    }

    updatePosition() {
        //group.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - group.rotation.y ) * 0.05;

        // move the object towards the camera
        this.group.position.z += this.speed;
        this.group.position.y += this.yOffset;
        // reset the object, if it's behind the camera
        if (this.group.position.z > 4080) {
            this.scene.remove(this.group);
        }
    }

    update() {
        // update font, time and position
        this.updateClock();
        this.updatePosition();
        if (this.font) {
            this.updateText();
        }
    }

};

// global vars
var container;
var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;

var instances = [];

var frameRate = 5;
document.getElementById("setFrameRate-Input").value = frameRate;

var instanceCreationTime = 1;
document.getElementById("setInstanceCreation-Input").value = instanceCreationTime;

// start
initGlobal();
animate();

document.getElementById("setFrameRate").addEventListener('click', function () {
    frameRate = document.getElementById("setFrameRate-Input").value;
}, false);

document.getElementById("setInstanceCreation").addEventListener('click', function () {
    instanceCreationTime = document.getElementById("setInstanceCreation-Input").value;
}, false);

function setDeceleratingTimeout(callback, factor, times) {
    var internalCallback = function(tick, counter) {
        return function() {
            if (--tick >= 0) {
                window.setTimeout(internalCallback, ++counter * factor);
                callback();
            }
        }
    } (times, 0);

    window.setTimeout(internalCallback, factor);
};

function initGlobal() {

    // container
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    // camera
    var cameraZ = 4000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(500, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, cameraZ);
    cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

    // lights
    var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.125);
    dirLight.position.set(0, 0, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(dirLight);

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // add resize listener
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // create first instance
    createInstance();

};

function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

};

function createInstance() {
    var newInstance = new timeFont(scene);
    newInstance.initClass();
    instances.push(newInstance);

    setDeceleratingTimeout(function() {
        createInstance();
        //console.log('create instace');
    }, 1000 / instanceCreationTime, 1);
}

function animate() {

    //requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }, 1000 / frameRate);

    render();

    // update test instance
    instances.forEach(instance => {
        instance.update();

        if (instance.timeFontZ > 4120) {
            delete instance;
        }

    });

}

function render() {

    camera.lookAt(cameraTarget);

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

PS: I updated the script on the link on my website. I only update the text, if there are seconds shown now. But it's still bad performance.

Comment: I decided to not update the text of the instance after its creation and not changing the seconds after initiation. The performance is now ok. Thanks threejs.org!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your app is the amount of geometries you allocate over time. When removing objects from the scene, you miss to call `dispose()` in order to free internal resources.

You remove objects at two places:

- In `updateText()` via `this.group.remove(this.textMesh1);`
- In `updatePosition()` via `this.scene.remove(this.group);`

In `updateText()` use this code to free the material and geometry:

```js
this.textMesh1.geometry.dispose();

if ( Array.isArray( this.textMesh1.material ) === true ) {

    for ( let material of this.textMesh1.material ) material.dispose();

} else {

    this.textMesh1.material.dispose();

}
```

In `updatePosition()`, use this generic code:

```js
this.group.traverse( function( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) {

        object.geometry.dispose();
        // release material like above

    }

} );
```

You can read more about memory management in this official guide:

[How to dispose of objects](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects)

Besides, try to load your fonts only once at the beginning and then reuse them. This will also avoid big frametimes since you avoid parsing overhead during your animation.

Comment: What a great input! Thanks! I'm able to dispose the geometry without problems. But when I try to dispose the material it says `this.textMesh1.material.dispose is not a function`.

Comment: Oh, you are using an array of materials. Then iterate over the array and remove the materials individually. Let me update the answer.

Comment: What a performance improvement! Thanks again to @Mugen87. You can see my updated script in action in the link above in my question.